# Exclude one JS file for a particular page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two JS files: mail.js and prototype.js 
prototype.js is from Lightbox plug-in and mail.js is validator and ajax for the contact us page. 
the problem is mail.js won't work when prototype.js is load *before or after* it.  
However I want to remove the prototype.js for contact page only where there's no need for lightbox.

I'm using php include as header. Is there a way to set the prototype.js as unload for the contact page only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header inlude, can't you just do an `if` statement like so:

```
if($_SERVER[’PHP_SELF’]!="contact_us.php"){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>';
}
```

Obviously replace the paths with the correct path. `PHP_SELF` is relative to domain, so if its in `/pages/` then `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` would equal `/pages/contact_us.php`

Correct answer was

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="contact_us.php"){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need to disable this JS file for the contact page not echo that out so the mail.js on the contact page works. How do you think we can get around it?

Comment: Placing that PHP script in your header means it will only use prototype.js on pages that aren't the contact_us.php page - use www.pastebin.com to paste your header.php file and I will amend it to work

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Yg5vJFm4 - that should do the trick, as it means PHP only echos the script if the page isn't `contact_us.php`

Comment: Right, I'm testing this on my localhost. Do I need to upload it online to get it fixed? Because right now I get this error: `Notice: Use of undefined constant ’PHP_SELF’ - assumed '’PHP_SELF’' in C:\wamp\www\roam\include\header.html on line 10`

`Notice: Undefined index: ’PHP_SELF’ in C:\wamp\www\roam\include\header.html on line 10`

Comment: The errors have been solved but it still loads the prototype.js with the contact page too. the addresses are correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3791/discussion-between-rickyduck-and-nima)